# php - composer update returns certificate verify failed

Tags: php, laravel, terminal, composer-php

When I try to do `composer install` or `composer update` I get an error message that says that the SSL certificate cannot be verified.

```
  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                 
  The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded:  
   SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:               
  error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate ver  
  ify failed                                                               
  Failed to enable crypto                                                  
  failed to open stream: operation failed
```

Has anybody an idea how I can solve this problem?

Comment: pls paste content of composer file

Comment: What is your current PHP version?

Comment: @JaredChu my PHP version is 5.6.24

Comment: @PeeHaa Sorry! Now the error message should be text.

Comment: Hmm, pls try this https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/2798#issuecomment-65489624

Answer (score 0):

I haven't encountered this myself, but after doing a quick search, I found a potential solution (if you're using PHP 5.6):

```
# update the ports tree (software list)
$ sudo port -v selfupdate
# install php (shortcut for compiling php with our required libs)
$ sudo port install php56
# install the mcrypt library for php
$ sudo port install php56-mcrypt
# install the curl library for php
$ sudo port install php56-curl
# configure which php version your system should use
$ sudo port select php php56
```

Source: https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/2798 (there are other potential solutions for this problem available there as well. Hope it helps!